# Интерфейсы в MVP

Tags: java, android, архитектура, mvp

Это наверное тысячный вопрос по MVP. Перечитал очень много статей, пересмотрел многие исходники из GitHub. Но мне до сих пор не понятны некоторые вещи. И исходя из одного примера погрузился в MVP, уже не помню название туториала. Но не в этом суть.

[Вот пример](https://github.com/omasapps/VKLite) где практикую с MVP. Структура такова:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где IChatsInteractor.java:

```
public interface IChatsInteractor {
    void getChatsByCount(int count, IChatsCallback chatsCallback);

    interface IChatsCallback{
        void onSuccess(ChatsModel chatsModel);

        void onFailure(String errorMessage);
    }
}
```

А `ChatsInteractorImpl` реализовывает `IChatsInteractor` и подтягивает данные с сервера. Полученные данные записывает в RealmDB и возвращает полученные данные в методе `ichatsCallback.onSuccess`, `ichatsCallback.onFailure` если ошибка.

Работает все это корректно. Но проблема в том, что я даже понятия не имею что вообще значит слово *interactor* (из урока начал использовать). Хочу переименовать, но никак не пойму как, на какое название и т.д.

**Вопросы:**

- Правильно ли то, что из за одного Activity (`ChatsActivity`) создал 5 классов: (`ChatsView` - он нужен, понимаю, `ChatsInteractorImpl` - работает с сервером.) Остальные 3 класса нельзя ли как то объединить или так правильно?
- Как видите для интеракторов создал отдельный пакет. Можно ли его запихнуть в папку `model`?
- Как правильно переименовать интеракторов на название основываясь на его функции?
- Стоить ли вытаскивать функцию записи полученных данных в базу данных из метода `getChatsByCount()` в классе `ChatsInteractorImpl`?
- И вообще, правильно ли я структурировал (спроектировал) весь MVP, то есть классы, методы?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Очень спорный вопрос, нет, это не значит, что он плох, даже наоборот - откровенно всё пишите. По вопросом, мне кажется понимаете правильно, я просто немного попытаюсь помочь. Я люблю вопросы по архитектуре, потому что даже `Google` колбасит, а различий множество `MVP`, `MVI`, `MVB`, `MVVM`, `MVVSP`, `VIPER`... Не говоря, о том что популярность некоторых полностью или частично меняет структурные решения. Но самое интересное, что действительно каждому, есть место быть, если разработчик считает, что это действительно удобно, во всех направлениях.

1. Если у вас всё хорошо помещалось в 1 `activity`, вы легко тестировали этот компонент и легко добавляли новые фичи или даже они не нужны в будущем, то возможно вы излишне использовали `MVP`. Да, именно так!, я видел множество мелких проектов, которые писали под разные решения, состоящие из несколько простых `activity`, и действительно тот же MVP там смотрится ужасно. Но! для больших проектов в `activity` могут использоваться и больше кол-во классов, десятки и сотни и так далее. Вот тогда это будет вашим спасением и во время добавления фичи, вы будете чувствовать себя комфортно, а сторонние разработчики намного быстрей смогут понять идею и приступить к помощи. 
   Объединить можно...., например обернуть фасадом интерфейсы и это смотрится хорошо и редактирование удобное для `MVP`.
2. Действительно `интеракторы` совмещают с моделью, но тогда модель быстро раздувается, и становится сложно тестируемой и заменяемой. Сейчас есть решения для таких ситуаций и это наверное отдельная тема. `Dagger 2` к примеру с `Rx`, делает эту прослойку незаметной.
3. Если и всё-таки решили так сделать, то модель должна предоставить необходимые данные а вот сама функция, как и всегда по `codeStyle` должна - быть говорящей.
4. Нет, `интеракторы` являются посредниками между `P` и `M` , и это его задача осуществить нужный запрос от необходимых менеджеров,  для получения или записи данных в модель и оповещать presenter о действиях, но это суть, на практике очень сильно бывает размыта.
5. Возможно. По `package` и нескольким классам тяжело сказать.

> UPDATE:

Сразу не увидел link на GitHub, что я могу добавить. Структуруа нормальная, хотя мне кажется MVP уже так мало кто использует, такой примитивный вариант, голый я бы сказал, хотя для понимания так и должно происходить. А вот используете, а точней не используете MVP, рассмотрим на примере LoginActivity.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmResults<AccessDataModel> accessDM = realm.where(AccessDataModel.class).findAll();


    if (accessDM != null) {
        AccessDataModel accessDataModel = accessDM.get(0);
        final String string = accessDataModel.getAccessToken() + "\n" +
                accessDataModel.getUserId() + "\n" +
                accessDataModel.getExpiresIn();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("data", string).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    realm.close();
}
```

CodeStyle упустим. Самое плохое, что вы смешали бизнес логику с View, не смотря на то что вы построили MVP, вы продолжаете все делать в Activity. Давайте рассмотирм один вариант на вашем примере: LifeCycle метод onStart() очень показательный. #109 line number

Кратко. Вы берете instance Realm, проверяете какие-то данные на доступ, если данные есть - формируете String и переходите в ChatActivity.
Как примерно должно быть: 
Когда срабатывает onStart Activity() вы просто сообщаете презентору об этом. И ваш метод должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mPresenter.onActivityStarted();
}
```

Замечу, что плохим тонном считается дублировать колбеки жизенного цикла компонентов 1 в 1:

> Плохо:

```
   @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        presenter.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

они должны для презенторов нести логику, но также нужно сходу отличать название, ибо когда другой компонент будет вызвать аналогичный метод или Fragment, вам придется не только переименовать, но и переходить внутрь, чтоб понять, что куда. Более того заметьте что вы вызываете презентер перед супер методом, тоже сомнительно, ибо если есть базовые классы или измененные State, может полвиять на логику работу в презентере то можете словить Leak.

в Presenter должно быть примерно так:

```
@Override
public void onActivityStarted() {
    boolean ifAccess = getInteractor.getAccess();
    if (ifAccess) getMvpView().navigateToChatsActivity(getInteractor.getAccessToken);
    else getMvpView().showAccessDenied();
}
```

во View если доступ есть:

```
@Override
public void navigateToChatsActivity(String accessToken) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("data", accessToken).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

если нет:

```
@Override
public void showAccessDenied() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "AccessDenied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

А интерактор разбирается с instance realm, и выполняент работу асинхронно. 
У меня в примере, более примитивно, чтоб вы уловили суть MVP, особенно если вы не работаете c Rx.

Comment: вроде как раз добавил, то что вы сейчас писали)

Comment: Почти) Насчет 3-пункта, вопрос о том как в моем случае переименовать, так как ничего в голову не приходит, вы видели что он делает, так как бы вы переименовали его? и насчет 4-пункта, вы говорите что интеракторы являются посредниками между P и M, а у меня запись в Realm происходит именно внутри интерактора, мне кажется его нужно вытащить оттуда, то есть из интерактора и записывать в базу в классе для модели которого у меня нет. Так вот как вытащить, то есть создать отдельный класс для метода и опять для него интерфейсы?

Comment: Ну я посоветую, чтоб вам проще было попробовать, ну этот вариант, иногда используется. Попробуйте создать такой более правильный класс в понимании MVP, назовите его например ApplicationModel, там в конструкторе создавайте инстанс Realm. Когда презентер будет создаваться, создавайте ему модель. И ваша проблема решиться, получить немного дописать мой код, только интеракторов не будет а будете сразу общаться с ApplicationModel в ней будут и кешировать и делать всё. Это плохо на самом деле, делать такой GodObject, но вы почуствуете удобсвто и будет легче понять дальше

Comment: Ну я частично написал, как правильно решать только вам. Ну вот пример. Получить доступ у модели можетt спросить mModel.getAccess(); А модель в то время общается с Realm, с SQlite, или просто из кеша вытаскивает или с Pref класса. и заметьте что такие под иерархия будет лечге заменяться, и даже на вашем примере связность уже сильно уменьшелась. В будущем чтоб подменить базу, например для тестирования на фейковую с тестовые значениями, вы будете знать, куда лезть а изменить нужно будет 1 класс. Жирный какой-то ответ получается, мб вам его разбить на более конкретные под вопросы=))

Comment: Еще такой вопрос, не по теме. Смотрите, стоит ли мне сразу изучать Dagger2 с Rx не до конца поняв всю эту архитектуру MVP с огромным количеством интерфейсов, или же нужно сперва до конца понять все эти связи между M и P. И второй вопрос, сколько времени уйдет на изучение RX и Dagger и начать свободно использовать в проектах, конечно понимаю, зависит от человека, но учитывая мой уровень текущий и в среднем если взять:?

Comment: ПО личному опыту не стоит всё сразу делать. Это же принцип декомпозици в методологиях, да и в психологиии.Нужно дробить задачи, так они решаются быстрей и запоминаются лучше. Хотя люди разные. По времени точно не скажу, дейсвительно вы абсолютно правы, зависит от человека и множества факторов. Я бы посоветовал применть MVP на уже рабочем приложении, или проекте при рефакторинге вы ощутите разницу я обещаю. Позже можно будет добавить Dagger2, там есть нюансы да и не всем он нравится, мы писали свой DI двольно удачно. Вы ButterKnife использзуете уже - они вместе неплохо смотрятся. Rx потом можно

Comment: Огромное вам человеческое спасибо, за то что уделили время и подняли мою самооценку) а то все вся говорят об Rx, Dagger, что я уже думал что я самый тупой на планете). Благодарю еще раз!